# Dotnetclr как настроить для linux?

Tags: c#, linux

linux ubuntu 10.16 x64

устанавливаю дот нет

https://localwire.pl/setup-net-core-on-ubuntu/

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://apt-mo.trafficmanager.net/repos/dotnet/ trusty main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dotnetdev.list' sudo apt-key adv --keyserver apt-mo.trafficmanager.net --recv-keys 417A0893 sudo apt-get -y update sudo apt-get -y install dotnet-dev-1.0.0-preview2-003121
```

при dotnet new получаю

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-virtual-machine:~$ dotnet new

Welcome to .NET Core!
--------------------- 
Learn more about .NET Core @ https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs. Use dotnet --help to see available commands or go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-docs. 
Telemetry
-------------- 
The .NET Core tools collect usage data in order to improve your experience. The data is anonymous and does not include commandline arguments. The data is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt out of telemetry by setting a DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to 1 using your favorite shell. You can read more about .NET Core tools telemetry @ https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry. 
Configuring...
------------------- 
A command is running to initially populate your local package cache, to improve restore speed and enable offline access. This command will take up to a minute to complete and will only happen once. Decompressing 100% 
3565 ms Ошибка сегментирования (сделан дамп памяти)
```

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего у вас относительно свежее ядро linux (4.6+), которое не поддерживается разработчиками dotnet.

Вообще, я бы рекомендовал пользоваться теми ОС, которые поддерживаются официально. Так же вы можете попробовать ночную сборку с https://github.com/dotnet/cli